# Run the last executed command in Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd

When using UNIX I use to type `!!` to run the last executed command.

How could I do the similar kind of operation on Windows command prompt?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<kbd>↑</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: but this is not a shell-alone feature, on some terminal the up arrow could be not useful (rare, but...); while the `!!` is an internal shell command that can have also other usages (btw uparrow followed by enter works for all other shells having history and terminal allowing the key), e.g. `for e in 1 2 3 4; do !!; done`

Comment: Agree, but that's not what the OP was asking for.  If you want to get fancy and execute !! equivalent in a script like your example you'd need to look at Powershell or install Cygwin.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use F7 to navigate the command history.
F1 will recover the last command character by character.

Answer (score 4):

**Windows PowerShell**

- `ihy`
- `Invoke-History`

**Sometimes** (if you didn't press <kbd>F9</kbd> & didn't choose an older command and if you didn't navigate through history using the keys <kbd>F5</kbd> / <kbd>F7</kbd>), the following keys can work in **cmd**:

- <kbd>F3</kbd> - gets the last command
- <kbd>F5</kbd> - gets the last command when you press it for the first time, then it iterates through the commands history
- <kbd>F8</kbd> - gets the last command when you press it for the first time, then it iterates through the commands history (it can also go from the first one to the last one)

A description for the functions above can be found on the [Microsoft website](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490894.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the up and down arrows or F3