# Repeat last command windows terminal

Tags: windows-terminal

On the Windows Terminal, **is there a way to repeat the last command by starting character, similar to the feature on a Unix Terminal?**

For example, if I type the command `cd ..` then laster type `!cd` on a Unix Terminal, it will do the command `cd ..` again. However, I can't find this feature on the Windows Terminal.

EDIT: Here is the terminal I am using (as installed by Windows, no specific configurations):
[image]

EDIT: I am aware that pressing the up/down arrow can navigate the history of commands, but I am in a situation where I use a multitude of different commands and use the arrow keys every time can be tedious. Accessing last command *by starting letter* will be a lot more useful, similar to the `!` command on Unix mentioned above.

**Two Solutions**

1. Ctrl + r, then type initial letter(s)
2. type initial letter(s), then F8

Comment: This depends upon the shell you are using like bash, powershell, etc. This is irrelevant to any specific terminal emulator.

Comment: @MelvinAbraham I am using the "Terminal" on Windows. See the edit in my post.

Comment: Check this other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177971/14664861).

Comment: @chubercik See my edit; pressing the arrow keys every time to navigate to a command I might not have used for the last 3/4 commands gets tedious. Even more so because there is not a set number of lines above the command I want is, I have to spend time thinking about which one it is, which is slow in the long run

Comment: Either press the "up" arrow key then press "Enter" or put it into a script and then run the script from the terminal.

Look into loops as well.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean put it into a script/run the script?

Comment: @MikeSmith I understood the point. As an analogy you can consider your PC hardware as terminal and the operating system installed on it as a shell. You can install any OS on your PC. Similarly, you can run any shell in the terminal (cmd, powershell, bash via WSL).

Comment: If you run bash on Windows Terminal, you will be able to use the mentioned commands as is

Comment: @MelvinAbraham I see. I'm pretty new to working with the terminal a lot; didn't even notice that. I am using PowerShell right now, but I also have WSL installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using *PowerShell* or *Bash* on your Windows Terminal, you can use a feature called **Reverse Search**. This will go through your history backwards and show you the recently used command based on the starting characters.

In order to activate reverse search, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> on the terminal and type out the initial characters and watch the recent command appear.

[image: Windows Terminal Reverse Search]

**Bonus tip:** You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> further to show next recent command

---

**Note:** This does not work for Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`)

Comment: When using 'Command Prompt' you can type the first (1 or more) letters of the command, and then hit 'F8' (This also works in Powershell)  (I have no clue why that info is missing here: [Keyboard shortcuts in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec#WindowsVersion=Windows_11), but see: [last executed command in Windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177971/run-the-last-executed-command-in-windows-command-prompt)

Comment: Thank you! This works great! @Luuk I didn't know about that one either. It works as well :)